# GTM Chaining multiple triggers and passing data from one tag to another

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I currently have a form with a related articles element that suggests the user related articles upon filling the form subject.

I'm trying to catch all the form submissions where a related article has been clicked.

I've created 2 triggers and 2 tags: 
The first fires once the user clicks on one of the related articles.

The second trigger fires once the user clicked on the form submission button.

I've also created a Trigger group that combines these 2 triggers, however, I'm having trouble with storing the clicked article text from the first trigger and using it in the tag.

Eventually I want to send to analytics the form subject and the clicked article text.

I know this can be easily achieved with dataLayer, but unfortunately, I cannot add any code to the site source.

Any ideas on how to implement this without using dataLayer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since standard variables are frequently overshadowed by new events, you probably should rewrite what you want to keep with a new name in the dataLayer. You do not need access to the site source to do so as long as your GTM snippet does not restrict GTM from adding custom html tags (blocking tag types is possible, but rarely used.)

You can do custom html tags with variable references like:

```
<script>
  dataLayer.push({importantclick:{{click element}} })
</script>
```

fired on one event and create a new DataLayer variable to retrieve `importantclick` at a later event on the same page.

(If for some reason you really can't write to the dataLayer, then using custom javascript variables, you can instead examine the contents of the dataLayer yourself to see contents that were overshadowed or write data elsewhere in the window environment to be fetched by another variable. But both of those practices are highly discouraged when working with javascript variables.)